# Adding rollover effect to skinned button in Flex

Tags: css, apache-flex

Using Flex 3, I have a Button which is skinned using PNGs specified in a CSS style sheet.

```
Button.addextra {  
    downSkin : Embed( source="img/add-extra-icon.png" ); 
    overSkin : Embed( source="img/add-extra-icon.png" ); 
    upSkin : Embed( source="img/add-extra-icon.png" ); 
    disabledSkin : Embed( source="img/add-extra-icon-disabled.png" ); 
}
```

My designer colleague would like to add a rollover effect of a hairline #999999 line outside the image. Is this possible (without creating a new overSkin png) using the standard Flex styles?

Comment: Does the image have transparency? Or, more to the point does the hairline need to be polygonal or is it a rectangle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you will need to change the overSkin, i think that would be the only way.

Answer (score 1):

What about drawing lines with Graphics?